# Convert byte[] array to a short[] array with half the length

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, byte, short, bitconverter

I have a `byte[200]` that is read from a file, representing a `short[100]` in little-endian format. This is how I read it:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    //fs.Seek(...)
    byte[] record = new byte[200];
    fs.Read(record, 0, record.Length);

    short[] target = new short[100];
    // magic operation that fills target array
}
```

I don't know what to put in "magic operation". I've read about `BitConverter`, but it doesn't seem to have a `BitConverter.ToShort` operation. Anyway, BitConverter seems to convert in a loop, whereas I would appreciate some way to "block copy" the whole array at once, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you're looking for [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(record, 0, target, 0, record.Length);
```

I *believe* that will preserve the endianness of the architecture you're on - so it may be inappropriate in some environments. You might want to abstract this into a method call which can check (once) whether or not it does what you want (e.g. by converting {0, 1} and seeing whether the result is {1} or {256}) and then either uses `Buffer.BlockCopy` or does it "manually" in a loop if necessary.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: If what is little-endian? The processor architecture? If so, I agree. Edited.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The bytes in the file are required to be in little-endian format. And I want to believe every common PC is little-endian too. Gonna test this right now.

Comment: `Buffer.BlockCopy` just copies the doesn't check/change endiannes. it is like `memcpy`

Comment: Am I confused? The endianess of the source will be the same as the target. Is it not a question of byte order? I think this just works.

Comment: @bansi: Yes, exactly. So it depends on whether that matches the data.

Comment: @Jodrell: It's a matter of the endianness of the original data vs the endianness of the machine the code is running on. The OP knows that the data is actually little-endian... if uses that data on a machine which is *big-endian*, he'll end up with the wrong results. You say "Is it not a question of byte order" as if that's different from endianness...

Comment: @JonSkeet, endianess begin which bit of the byte has the highest order. Byte order being which byte of a word has the highest order. They are conceivably different but, I must admit confusion.

Comment: @Jodrell: In my experience, it's rarely used for *bit* labelling, but for ordering of *bytes* within a larger value - as per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness. (I don't know of a different name for the bit labelling concept, although Wikipedia uses "bit endianness" to mean pretty much that.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, **m**ost **s**ignificant **b**it seems to be the term, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Comment: Your answer is tested, and it works fine. Thanks again!